# Snowflake "Invalid UTF8 detected in string SNOWFLAKE" using PUT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've got a csv file with this content:

```
"Compañía","Aeropuerto Base","Año","Clase","Grupo Compañía","Mes","Movimiento","País","Servicio","Tipo Avión","Tipo Tráfico","Operaciones Totales"
"2 EXCEL AVIATION LTD","ADOLFO SUÁREZ MADRID-BARAJAS","2020","UE SCHENGEN","Total","","","","","","","0"
"2 EXCEL AVIATION LTD","ADOLFO SUÁREZ MADRID-BARAJAS","2020","UE NO SCHENGEN","Total","","","","","","","4"
"2 EXCEL AVIATION LTD","ADOLFO SUÁREZ MADRID-BARAJAS","2020","INTERNACIONAL","Total","","","","","","","2"
```

I've uploaded it to snowflake using the stage feature:

```
PUT 'file://C:\\tmp\\opc2020.csv' @demo_stage;
```

I've created a file format:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT demo_file_format TYPE = 'CSV' field_delimiter = ',';
```

If I try to query the content:

```
SELECT C.$1 FROM @demo_stage (file_format => 'demo_file_format') C
```

I get an error:

```
SQL Error [100144] [22000]: Invalid UTF8 detected in string '0xFF0xFE"0x00C0x00o0x00m0x00p0x00a0x000xF10x000xED0x00a0x00"0x00'
  File 'opc2020.csv.gz', line 1, character 1
  Row 1, column "TRANSIENT_STAGE_TABLE"["$1":1]
```

If I add the VALIDATE_UTF8 = false attribute then I can query the stage but losing the UTF8 characters and with some unexpected whitespace between characters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT dbt_demo_file_format TYPE = 'CSV' field_delimiter = ',' VALIDATE_UTF8 = TRUE;


��" C o m p a � � a "                                            |
 " 2   E X C E L   A V I A T I O N   L T D "     
 " 2   E X C E L   A V I A T I O N   L T D "     
 " 2   E X C E L   A V I A T I O N   L T D "     
 " 2   E X C E L   A V I A T I O N   L T D "     
 " 2   E X C E L   A V I A T I O N   L T D "     
 " 2   E X C E L   A V I A T I O N   L T D "     
 " 2   E X C E L   A V I A T I O N   L T D "
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What character set was used in the first place when the file was created? Your FILE FORMAT should have ENCODING set to the original character set otherwise you would get this issue if it was not UTF-8 (Snowflake's default character set, see [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-file-format.html#alter-file-format))

Comment: According to notepad the original file was encoded using UTF-16 LE

Comment: That probably answers why you get the issue. You will need to regenerate the file using UTF-8 and then it should work.

Comment: Actually, I added this encoding (ENCODING = 'UTF-16 LE') to the file format and now it works perfectly. It ended looking like this: CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT demo_file_format TYPE = 'CSV' field_delimiter = ',' ENCODING = 'UTF-16 LE' VALIDATE_UTF8 = TRUE FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"';

Comment: @Sergiu if you could elaborate your answer I would gladly mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the original file was generated using a different character set than UTF-8 then you would get into this issue.

If you know the character set used to generate the file then you can set into the FILE FORMAT statement the **ENCODING** parameter to the correct value.

In your case if the original file was created using UTF-16LE then your CREATE FILE FORMAT would look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT demo_file_format TYPE = 'CSV' field_delimiter = ',' ENCODING = 'UTF-16 LE' VALIDATE_UTF8 = TRUE FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"';
```

More information on character sets and encoding is on our docs [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html).